# Dynamically Created Checkbox, Check Event Listener

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am displaying a list of Services.  I don't know how many services will be in the list.  So I create a dynamic list with a checkbox for each service listed.  I know how to pull the state of the checkbox if the form is submitted but in this case I need to know if the boxes are selected without the form being submitted.  I've looked at using event listeners but can't figure out how I can point to the appropriate checkbox.  How can I check for the state of each checkbox without the form being submitted?  I am using the value '$J' to give each checkbox a unique name.

Php and HTML:

```
for ($J = 0; $J < $size; ++$J) {
    if ($sp->sosts[$J] == 'A') {
        $lbl   = $sp->solbl[$J];  
echo <<<_END
        <form method = 'POST' action = ''>
            <div id = 'currentsrv'>
                <div class = 'servhdr'>
                    <input type = 'checkbox' class = 'servcb' 
                        name = "srvcb$J">
                    <div class = 'servtitle'>
                        <span id = 'servlbl'> Service : </span>
                        <span id = 'servnm'> $lbl </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
_END;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: One question is _when_ you _"need to know if the boxes are selected"_. As soon as the user clicks on one of the checkboxes? Or before submitting the form(s)?

Comment: _sidenote:_ I don't thinks it's a good idea (unless I miss something) to create a new `<form>` for each checkbox.

Comment: Don't repeat **unique** ids.

Comment: In your eventlistener (for what ever event) you can get all checkboxes via [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Or if you need to bind an eventlistener to all of them

Comment: You're comment is why I'm reluctant to use this site Jonathan.  No one provided an answer that completely works for my scenario.  I'm new to this type of coding so it's takes me a bit longer to figure out how to make it fit.  And it amazes me that I get more negative rep for just taking too long to respond.

Comment: @SiriusGD Your non-answer to the first two questions is one reason why you didn't get provided an _"answer that completely works for my scenario"_ - because we don't know your scenario. This is why we ask and wait for response (to questions that don't need any figuring out).

Comment: @Jeff Generally before I come to a conclusion or make a hasty reply I'd like to test out the code and see if there is anything I can pull from it to make it work.  The rude comment made to me earlier is what this site has become well known for.  He gave me all of 4 minutes before he decided I "was sleeping".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to have to each checkbox an id, and in Javascript you can do this (if you know what the IDs will be):

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("theID");
if(checkbox.checked) {
  //do something if the checkbox is checked
}

//alternatively, use a variable to store whether the ckeckbox is checked

var isMyCheckboxChecked = checkbox.checked
```

OR, if you just want to know how many of the checkboxes are checked, you can make them have the same class, then:

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass");
var counter = 0; //counter for how many checkboxes are checked
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
    counter++;
  }
}
console.log("" + counter + " checkboxes are checked.");
```

Comment: Or is it an event that you want?

Comment: This looks like it may work.  There are some other things that come into play so I have to tweak it and see if it will work for me.  Thanks.  I'm very new to Javascript so at times it takes a little while for me to wrap my brain around it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to show you the principle.  I've used jQuery for convenience.

In the output, `true` represents checked and `false` represents unchecked.

```js
function printCheckboxStates(){
  let states = $('input[type=checkbox]').toArray().map(c => c.checked);
  let checked = states.filter(checked => checked).length;
  console.log(`${checked} checkboxes are checked`, states);
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
 <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<button onclick="printCheckboxStates()">
 Get checkbox states
</button>
```

Comment: `$(c).is(':checked')` <-- don't do this.  If you already have a reference to the element, just use `c.checked`

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the tip.  Updated my answer.  I seem to remember that property being unreliable in the past, hence `:checked`.

Comment: `:checked` is one of those pseudo selectors that really doesn't make much sense, unless you are adding it to a filter, or in the selector itself.  If you have the plain object already, it's just a directly property access.  If you already have the object as a jQuery object, then `prop('checked')` is less work